# What happens in Nekogames Parameters when the mysterious "beat" bar fills up?

Tags: parameters

In [Nekogames' Parameters](http://www.nekogames.jp/g.html?gid=PRM), between the status area and the map area, there is a mysterious bar that fills up with blue as you pick up experience and treasure, finally becoming cyan. Has anyone else figured out what this mode means?

I've tried fighting when it's like this (I still get hurt), as well as gambling (I still lose) and more looting (seems about the same) and buying things (they cost the same). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

When my bar filled and changed colors, it unlocked the chest in the top right corner, which gave me $200 for every level I had gained at that point.

Comment: I thought the five chest squares were unlocked by getting the "NEKOGAMES" letters, but the beat bar makes much more sense. Will try to confirm!

Comment: I can confirm that this is indeed what happens (`$200 x [Current Level]`). To have an easier time filling up the bar, increase your ACT and RCV. @bollwyvl when you get all the "NEKOGAMES" letters you unlock a square that doubles your (current) ATK.